# invert filename order script

Tags: python

I have a set of files which the names follow this pattern: xxx - 001, xxx - 002 ..... xxx - 700

What I would like to do it`s a python script which I can invert the order of the name of the files, doing the xxx - 700 to be the xxx - 0001!

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post the code you've tried and any hint as to what problems you're having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean a Python script to rename all the files?

First, you'll need to do the renaming into a different directory, or as soon as you rename "xxx - 700" to "xxx - 001", it will overwrite the existing file "xxx - 001". So have it rename "xxx - 700" to "temp/xxx - 001", and "xxx - 699" to "temp/xxx - 699", etc. Then manually move everything from temp back to the current directory.

The script should use [os.rename](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.rename) to rename each file.

Now, just have the script use [os.listdir](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.listdir) to find all the files in the directory. Perhaps find the one with the highest number and ensure that the directory contains files with all numbers from 001 to the highest (or at some point there will be an error).

Now iterate over all numbers *i* from 001 to the highest, and rename each file from "xxx - *i*" to "xxx - (*highest* - *i*)".

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate through the directory using the `glob` module, then using `regex` find the two groups in the file name and then you can do a `shutil.move` to rename the files.